# How to generate a Map backed by a List

Tags: java, collections, wrapper

I have a data model that looks like this:

```
class CustomField {
    String key;
    String value;
}
```

From an API that I can get instances of `List<CustomField>`. The keys are unique in the list, which means that this collection really should be a `Map<String, String>`. Operating on this list is a pain, since every operation requires iteration to check for existing keys (CustomField doesn't implement equals either)

How can I create a `Map<String, String>` "view" backed by this list, so that I can operate on it using the Map interface?

I want a generic method like: `<T, K, V> Map<K, V> createMapBackedByList(List<T> list, BiFunction<K, V, T> elementMapper, Function<T, K> keyMapper, Function<T, V> valueMapper)` or similar.

It would use the functions to map between the list elements and map keys and values.

The important thing here is that I want changes to the map to be reflected in the underlying list, which is why the Streams API does not work here...

EDIT: I can't modify the API or the CustomField class.

Comment: Why don't you just create a `Map<String,String>` from the `List<CustomField>` and turn it back into a `List` after you're done? Do you really need to alter the underlying structure directly?

Comment: Probably you can get the list of values of a map by `map.values()`.

Comment: You can write a new `Map` implementation, probably extending [`AbstractMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html).

Comment: Create comparator to do sorting by customfields's key. Then use binarySearch of collection to find if particular customField is there.

Comment: @Jack That's possible, but I want something that's reusable and won't require me to write the changes back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying to implement it myself and basing it on an AbstractList. It was actually easier than I first though...

```
public class ListBackedMap<T, K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> {
    private final List<T> list;
    private final BiFunction<K, V, T> keyValueToElement;
    private final Function<T, K> elementToKey;
    private final Function<T, V> elementToValue;

    public ListBackedMap(List<T> list, BiFunction<K, V, T> keyValueToElement, Function<T, K> elementToKey, Function<T, V> elementToValue) {
        this.list = list;
        this.keyValueToElement = keyValueToElement;
        this.elementToKey = elementToKey;
        this.elementToValue = elementToValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return list.stream()
                .collect(toMap(elementToKey, elementToValue))
                .entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V previousValue = remove(key);
        list.add(keyValueToElement.apply(key, value));
        return previousValue;
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

It's not very performant (or thread safe), but it seems to do the job well enough.

Example:

```
List<CustomField> list = getList();
ListBackedMap<CustomField, String, String> map = new ListBackedMap<>(
        list,
        (key, value) -> new CustomField(key, value),
        CustomField::getKey,
        CustomField::getValue);
```

Comment: I am glad that I could point you in a good direction. In order to "complete" your example you might want to show how you instantiate that class (assuming that you are using various lambdas to that "mapping" from fields to key/value). At least me; I am curious how you do that ;-)

Comment: I suppose this would work with a Set as well, provided the element equality is based on the key.

Comment: @GhostCat Updated with an example :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

Write your own

```
 public class ListBackedMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
```

which takes some sort of `List<Pair<K,V>>` on creation; and "defers" to that. Of course, that requires that your `CustomField` class implements that `Pair` interface. (which you would probably need to invent, too)

( alternatively: your new class `extends AbstractMap<K,V>` to safe you most of the work ).

And now your methods simply return an instance of such a Map.

In other words: I am not aware of a built-in wrapper that meets your requirements. But implementing one yourself should be pretty straight forward.

Edit: given the fact that the OP can't change the `CustomField` class, a simple helper such as

```
 interface <K, V> MapEntryAdapter {
   K getKey();
   V getValue();
 }
```

would be required; together with a specific implementation that knows how to retrieve key/value from an instance of `CustomField`. In this case, the map would be backed by a `List<MapEntryAdapter<K, V>>` instead.

Comment: Sure, this is entirely possible, but not trivial, and I was hoping to find something like it in any of the popular collections frameworks (such as Google Guava or Apache Commons).

I can't change CustomField so the Pair solution is out of the question...

Comment: I can help with the Pair thing - as that construct isn't really required; we just add *another* layer of abstraction (that always helps to solve problems) instead. See my updates.

Comment: I took your advice about extending the AbstractMap and it was actually pretty simple in the end. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43805008/940731